# Remove deadline shortcut?

Tags: emacs, org-mode

Is there an easy way (with a keyboard shortcut) to remove a deadline or a schedule without actually closing the task?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shortcut: `C-u C-c C-s`.

Why this works

1. to find all methods with schedule, do `C-h a`, enter "schedule". There seems to be only

   ```
   org-schedule is an interactive compiled Lisp function in
   ‘../elpa/org-9.0.9/org.el’.

   (org-schedule ARG &optional TIME)

   Insert the SCHEDULED: string with a timestamp to schedule a TODO item.
   With one universal prefix argument, remove any scheduling date from the item.
   With two universal prefix arguments, prompt for a delay cookie.
   With argument TIME, scheduled at the corresponding date.  TIME can
   either be an Org date like "2011-07-24" or a delta like "+2d".
   ```
2. so you need to call `org-schedule` "with one universal prefix argument". See https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Prefix-Command-Arguments.html. The universal prefix argument is just `C-u`. In code, this is handled at `org.el` in `org--deadline-or-schedule`:

   ```
   (pcase arg
     (`(4)
      (when (and old-date log)
    (org-add-log-setup (if deadline? 'deldeadline 'delschedule)
               nil old-date log))
      (org-remove-timestamp-with-keyword keyword)
      (message (if deadline? "Item no longer has a deadline."
         "Item is no longer scheduled.")))
   ```

PS: The Emacs-geeks live at https://emacs.stackexchange.com.